# How to navigate to sw_front view using SWRevealViewcontroller in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealViewController to impliment sidebar in my ios app.I have followed [appcoda](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/) tutorial to implement it.As per this tutorial I have made two segue's sw_front which is for main viewcontroller(rootviewcontroller) and second one is sw_rear which is for sidebar.I am successfully able to implement it using this tutorial,but now I am getting problem in navigating from sw_rear view to sw_front segue.Please, help me if anyone knows this kind of problem.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? I understand you have a problem for navigating from sw_rear to sw_front but what is actually the error? Is it not working?

Comment: No, their is not any error, it is working fine but, If i enter in one of the viewcontroller  from the sidebar menu, now from this viewcontroller  I wanted to navigate to main view i.e. sw_front segue rootviewcontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This my slidemenu.m

All you have to do Create table of your menu Items , Each item has identifier

Click right in each item , choose reveal view controller

that all
[image]

```
    #import "SlideMenu.h"
    #import "SWRevealViewController.h"
    @interface SlideMenu ()

    @end

    @implementation SlideMenu{
        NSArray *menu_items;
        NSArray*thumbies;
        NSArray*indentifer;
    }


    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
    {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        indentifer = @[@"report_view" ,@"ann_view" , @"message_view" , @"calendar_view" , @"schedule_view" , @"about_view" , @"student_view" ];

        menu_items = @[@"Reports" , @"Messages" , @"Announcement" , @"Calendar" ,@"Schedule" ,@"About us",@"back to Students"];

        thumbies = @[@"report.png" , @"message.jpg" ,@"ann.jpg", @"calendar.jpg" , @"schedule.png" , @"about.png" ];

    }



    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    #pragma mark - Table view data source

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {

        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {

        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return [menu_items count];
    }


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSString * cell_identifer = [indentifer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cell_identifer forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cell== nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cell_identifer];
        }

        //cell.textLabel.text = [menu_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ];

        return cell;
    }





    #pragma mark - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        if ([segue isKindOfClass:[SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]]) {
            SWRevealViewControllerSegue *swsegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*)segue;

            swsegue.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue *rvc_segue , UIViewController * svc , UIViewController *dvc){
                UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
                [navController setViewControllers:@[dvc] animated:NO];
                [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition:FrontViewPositionLeft animated:YES];
            };

        }
    }


    @end
```

**UPDATE ANSWER FOR XCODE 6.4**

**FULL EXAMPLE**

create viewController to hold `SWRevealViewController` class

this view has rear (slide menu items) , front (implemented items)
please check screen shots

[image]

[image]

from your slide menu viewController class to each item

this table view implement my slide menu items , I use push method

(SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController)

[image]

here is connection inspector before navigation controller

[image]

hope this answer all your questations

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, Can you please explain me how I have to use it, more briefly?

Comment: @minafawzy.. Hi. i am using SWRevealviewController for iOS 6 project. And as per your instructions i am not getting "SWRevealViewControllerSegue" instead i am getting "SWRevealViewControllerPushSegue" or "SWRevealViewControllerSetSegue". What should i do?

Comment: sorry for late answer use SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController instead I will update my answer

Comment: @MinaFawzy can you send yor exmple code. so i can download and implement easily. thank x in advance...

Comment: menu_items array was dynamic how can we implement with out static cells?